# $X|A=a\in W(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b})$ with $A\in \Gamma(p,\theta)$. Show $X^{b}$ is Pareto-distributed

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I am working on this question from the book $\textit{An Intermediate Course in Probability}$ by Allan Gut:

Show that a suitable power of a Weibull-distributed random variable whose parameter is gamma-distributed is Pareto-distributed. More precisely, show that if

$X|A=a\in W(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b})\quad \text{with}\quad A\in \Gamma(p,\theta)$

then $X^{b}$ has a (translated) Pareto-distribution.

$\underline{\text{My attempt at solution:}}$

$W(\lambda, k): \quad  f_{X}(x)=\frac{k}{\lambda}(\frac{x}{\lambda})^{k-1}e^{-(\frac{x}{\lambda})^{k}}$

$W(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}): \quad f_{X}(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{b}}{\frac{1}{a}}(\frac{x}{\frac{1}{a}})^{\frac{1}{b}-1}e^{-(\frac{x}{\frac{1}{a}})^{\frac{1}{b}}}=\frac{1}{b}a^{\frac{1}{b}}x^{\frac{1}{b}-1}e^{-(ax)^{\frac{1}{b}}}$

I try to find the distributions of $X$ first, to raise it to $b$ later.

$P(X=x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X|A=a)\cdot f_{A}(a)\,da$

$f_{X}(x)=\int_{a=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b}a^{\frac{1}{b}}x^{\frac{1}{b}-1}e^{-(ax)^{\frac{1}{b}}}\cdot  \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}a^{p-1}e^{-\frac{a}{\theta}}\,da\\
=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{b}-1}}{b\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}\int_{0}^{\infty}a^{\frac{1}{b}+p-1}e^{-((ax)^{\frac{1}{b}}+\frac{a}{\theta})}\,da$

Is this the right way to go? I have not find a solutution to the last integral yet.

Comment: Please look at the end of Allan Gut book and take the formula for p.d.f. of Weibull distribution from there.

Comment: Oh, thank you! That clearified some things. I was using the wrong parametrization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parametrization was wrong. The correct one is:

$W(\alpha,\beta), \, \alpha,\beta>0\quad f(x)=\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}x^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}e^{-(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{\beta}}}{\alpha})},\quad x>0$

$W(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b}),\, a,b>0\quad f(x)=abx^{b-1}e^{-(ax^{b})},\quad x>0$

$f_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}abx^{b-1}e^{-(ax^{b})}\cdot  \frac{1}{\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}a^{p-1}e^{-\frac{a}{\theta}}\,da\\
=\frac{bx^{b-1}}{\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}\int_{0}^{\infty}a^{p}e^{-(ax^{b}+\frac{a}{\theta})}\,da\\
=\frac{bx^{b-1}}{\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}\int_{0}^{\infty}a^{p}e^{-a(x^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta})}\,da\\
=\frac{bx^{b-1}}{\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}\int_{0}^{\infty}a^{p}e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\,da$

$U=a^{p},\quad dV=e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\\
dU=pa^{p-1}\,da,\quad V=-(\frac{\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\\
-(\frac{a^{p}\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\Big|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}-(\frac{\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}pa^{p-1}\,da\\
=\frac{p\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}a^{p-1}e^{-(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\, da$

$U=a^{p-1},\quad dV=e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\\
dU=(p-1)a^{p-2}\,da,\quad V=-(\frac{\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\\
=\frac{p\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1}\Big(-(\frac{a^{p-1}\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\Big|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}-(\frac{(p-1)a^{p-2}\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\,da\Big)\\
=\frac{p(p-1)\theta^{2}}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}a^{p-2}e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\,da$

$\bullet\\
\bullet\\
\bullet$

$\frac{p!\theta^{p-1}}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p-1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}ae^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\, da\\
U=a,\quad dV=e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})},\\
dU=da,\quad V=-(\frac{\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\\
\frac{p!\theta^{p-1}}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p-1}}(\frac{\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a(\frac{\theta x^{b}+1}{\theta})}\,da\\
=\frac{p!\theta^{p}}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p}}(\frac{\theta}{\theta x^{b}+1})\\
=\frac{p!\theta^{p+1}}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p+1}}$

$\frac{bx^{b-1}}{\Gamma(p)\theta^{p}}\cdot \frac{p!\theta^{p+1}}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p+1}}\\
=\frac{bx^{b-1}p\theta}{(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p+1}}=\frac{bx^{b-1}p\theta}{\theta^{p+1} x^{b+p+1}(\theta x^{b}+1)^{p+1}}\\
=\frac{bx^{b-1}x^{-(b+p+1)}p\theta \theta^{-(p+1)}}{(1+\theta^{-1}x^{-b})^{p+1}}=\frac{bx^{b-1-b-p-1}p\theta^{-p}}{(1+\theta^{-1}x^{-b})^{p+1}}\\
=\frac{bpx^{-p-2}\theta^{p}}{(1+\theta^{-1}x^{-b})^{p+1}}$

$f_{X}(x)=\frac{pbx^{b-1}(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{(x^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p+1}}\\
F_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{pbt^{b-1}(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{(t^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p+1}}\, dt$

$u=t^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta},\quad du=bt^{b-1}\,dt$

$F_{X}(x)=\Big[\frac{(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{(t^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}\Big]_{0}^{x}=\frac{(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{(x^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}$

$F_{X}(x)=P(X<x)=P(U^{b}<x)=P(U<x^{\frac{1}{b}})=\frac{(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{((x^{\frac{1}{b}})^{b}+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p+1}}=\frac{(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{(x+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p+1}}$

$f_{X}(x)=\frac{p(\frac{1}{\theta})^{p}}{(x+\frac{1}{\theta})^{p+1}}$